# PostgreSQL LISTEN/NOTIFY not working

Tags: php, postgresql, notify, listen

Here is the basic setup:

- A PHP script writes to a table in a database and then issues `NOTIFY job_added`.  It then begins listening for a response by issuing `LISTEN job_complete`
- A daemon (written in C) has already issued a `LISTEN jod_added` and hence wakes up and processes the table.
- The daemon processes the table and writes results into a results table before calling `NOTIFY job_complete`
- The PHP script then wakes up and retrieves the result from the results table.

All but the last step is working.  The daemon uses libpq and I have checked the success of the `NOTIFY` issued by the daemon once it has added the result to the results table.

So I think the problem lies with the PHP script.  Here is the pertitent code:

```
$id = query("INSERT into jobs_table (/* details not important */) VALUES (/* */) RETURNING id");

query("NOTIFY job_added");
//daemon wakes up and does its thing.

query("LISTEN job_complete".$id);

$time = time();
while((time() - $time) < 30) {
    $notify = pg_get_notify($conn);
    if($notify) {
        // Never gets here
        if($notify['message']=="job_complete".$id) {
            //our job has completed
            break;
        }
    }
    usleep(25000);
}
```

So we add to the jobs table, issue a `LISTEN` and loop for 30seconds until we get the notification that our job is done.

The problem is that `pg_get_notify()` never picks up the `NOTIFY` issued by the daemon.  Note, the `NOTIFY` issued by the daemon happens after the `LISTEN` by the php script, I checked.

Is there anything I am doing that is completely wrong? Btw, I am well aware query() isn't a built-in function, it was added for brevity.

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to use [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php), [`usleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) or [`time_sleep_until`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time-sleep-until.php) rather than running a loop until time runs out.

Comment: Maybe you're notifying on "job_complete" instead of "job_complete".$id?

Comment: brian-l: Afraid not.  In the daemon I basically do `snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "NOTIFY job_complete%d", job_id);` and then call `PQexec(conn, buf);` from libpq.

Comment: Problem solved.  I wasn't passing a connection handle to pg_get_notify, I was passing a database object (for a custom class) instead. Silly me! Apologies.

Comment: You might consider posting this as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 3):

I would be willing to bet that the problem is that you are not committing the transaction.  Notifies are raised on commit.

Try:

```
 query('COMMIT');
```

See if that raises the notification for you.